# fast 2d array contains 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

What's a good way to implement that one 2d array contains another?

eg:

```
A = [0, 0, 0]
    [1, 1, 2]
    [0, 3, 4]

B = [1, 2]
    [3, 4]

C = [0, 0, 0]
    [1, 1, 2]

D = [1, 1, 2]
    [9, 3, 4]

contains(A, B) // true
contanis(A, C) // true
contains(A, D) // false
```

I've tried to do this. Basically, it just traverses A until A[row][col] == B[0][0], and if it finds one, then does a compare A with B from [row][col].

```
public static boolean contains(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

    // search for matching first element
    // only want to search up to a-b size
    for(int ra = 0; ra <= a.length - b.length; ra++) {
        for(int ca = 0; ca <= a[0].length - b[0].length; ca++) {

            // found matching first element
            if(a[ra][ca] == b[0][0]) {
                boolean tempFound = true;

                // check matching array from starting element
                for(int rb = 0; rb < b.length; rb++) {
                    for(int cb = 0; cb < b[0].length; cb++) {
                        if(b[rb][cb] != a[ra + rb][ca + cb]) {
                            tempFound = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!tempFound) break;
                }

                // found it
                if(tempFound) return true;

                // otherwise keep trying to find first matching element
            }

        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

But that just seems incredibly convoluted and brutish for something that looks like it can be done in a simpler way. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it most basic terms ... you are essentially performing a substring search, except you have integers instead of characters and you are not addressing the array sequentially.  So reduce this problem down to a substring search algorithm.

Using a slightly altered Boyer–Moore search algorithm, you would achieve much better performance.  Think of it as a 2-D Boyer Moore search algorithm.